# Python selenium - compile with embedded webdriver and browser

Tags: python, selenium

I want to automate webpage interaction which involves clicking several buttons on the Web UI. I decided to use selenium.

Fortunately, my tests with selenium were successful. However, I will be compiling the script using pyinstaller and shipping the compiled version of the script to end users. The problem is I wouldn't know which browser they use nor can I ask them to install webdrivers.

Is there a way to embed webdriver and browser in compiled binary?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the —add-binary argument   In pyinstaller to add the chromedriver as binary and in your script call the driver (e.g chromedriver) from a relative path:

`webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver/path')`

See [pyinstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html) for more info.